# What are these small numbers, and squiggly lines on this guitar sheet music

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music

I'm trying to learn the Twilight at the Zocalo, and I found some odd notation I havent seen before. I'm asking for what these symbols are:

- The squiggly line between 2 notes
- The small numbers next to notes
- The small dashes connecting the numbers

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but the roman numerals just say to play that single note at that fret?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10):

The numbers tell you which left hand finger to use (index being 1, pinky being 4 - thumb not included on guitar of course).

The Roman numerals tell you which *position* to play in. This is similar to which fret, as you suggest, but indicates the fret position of the left hand, not the actual note. This is done by putting a Roman numeral for the fret which the first finger (index) would be at. So, for instance, in position X (which is tenth position) an E at fret 12 would be played with the third finger. You can see this in the first of your excerpts. This makes sense: the first finger would be at fret 10, second at fret 11 and third at fret 12, when in tenth position.

The "wiggly" line denotes a glissando, more commonly known as a slide. Having said that, the example above is rather unusual, as it suggests you slide down just three frets and then switch to using a different finger! I would play this by sliding down further than the note after the slide, to fifth position, before then putting the third finger on fret 7. This has a dual benefit: it makes the switch of fingering easier to execute; it also makes the slide more obvious and expressive, as a slide over just two frets distance is a little difficult to hear.

**(Thanks to @Tim for pointing out some silly errors in this answer - should be correct now...)**

Comment: isn't it D down to B - a three fret slide? Still weird with a finger change though.If you go to position V, would your 3rd finger be on fifth fret?

Comment: Oops! You're absolutely right, I'll correct that! And yes, I think that fingering is a bit weird. It usually makes more sense to slide from one note to another using the same finger. That's why I suggest going "too far" to fret five and then putting the 3rd finger on fret 7 (which I also got wrong and need to correct...) Thanks, @Tim...

Comment: I thought a slur, as in a short curved line between two notes was a slide. Or a pull off. Is the squiggle more specific?

Comment: You can use wavy or straight lines for a gliss. (although I think a straight line looks neater). If you use a slur as well, this would suggest you don't repick the note you slide to.

Comment: I know what you're getting at with slurs though; you often see these used as an "indeterminate" slide onto or away from a note, a "scoop" or "fall", for instance.

Comment: I tend to slur, as when transcribing, sometimes it's difficult to tell which is which being played.Or it could be a 'pre bend let down'. Either that, or it's the alcohol...